# Compare rapidjson::Documents

Tags: c++, c, json, rapidjson

I have two RapidJSON documents. One I created at runtime and other one is read from disk.

I want to compare if these two documents are similar or not. What is the best way to compare RapidJSON documents?

My JSON looks like this

```
{
    "SimpleCompany:Manager":
    {
        "read":true,
        "update":true,
        "delete":true,
        "insert":true
    },
    "SimpleCompany:Manager":
    {
        "read":true,
        "update":true,
        "delete":true,
        "insert":true
    },
}
```

Comment: what do you want to hear? Are they strings? Hash them maybe?

Comment: yes these are values are strings... I just want to read those value and match them with my other Json document object. is these any build in function that can compare two json objects ?

Comment: Currently we are working on a branch to provide `Value::operator==()` at https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues/91

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  When I try to compare strcmp(newDocument["read"] , origDocument["read"])) I' getting //error no operator [] matches these operands. I get that when I try to do this too const rapidjson::Value& a1 = newDocument["read"];

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now, `GenericValue` overrides the `operator==` with other values, strings or primitives:

```
bool operator==(const GenericValue<...>& rhs) const;
bool operator==(const Ch* rhs) const;
bool operator==(const std::basic_string<Ch>& rhs) const;
bool operator==(const T& rhs) const;
```